# Discount in shopping cart

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, shopping-cart

I'm trying to add the Discount Field in the Total section of the cart, but I don't understand where i can find the value.

I'd like to see in the cart page:

Subtotal    €2,297.00
**Discount  ????**
Shipping & Handling €0.00

Where can i take this information?

thanks in advance

Comment: try with the sales_quote_save_after event to add the discount

Comment: Have you applied coupon code? Or you want to programatically give discount to customer, It is unclear from your question.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not clear, I 'd like to see the discount of the products in a field, the discount of the coupun works.